# Hashmap values not appended to Alertdialog

Tags: android, hashmap, android-alertdialog

I have a callog(displayed in an alert dialog) in an arraylist that has been sorted using an hashmap, any time I try to view this callog it shows just the result of the calllog query but in my logcat it shows the numbers properly sorted. Please how can I append this result in the logcat to the alert dialog? I have been battling with it for days and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
final List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] strFields = { android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,  }; 
            String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC LIMIT 10   ";                  



        final Cursor cursorCall = EmergencyButtonActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, strFields,
                    null, null, strOrder);
                  this.sortNumber();



        while (cursorCall.moveToNext()){

            String names = cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
             allNumbers.add(names)
                    }
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EmergencyButtonActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Frequent Contacts");
                android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item) {
                        cursorCall.moveToPosition(item);
                         EditText phoneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
                        String selectedNumber =cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                        selectedNumber = selectedNumber.replace("-", "");
                        phoneInput.setText(selectedNumber);

                        Toast.makeText(EmergencyButtonActivity.this, cursorCall.getString(cursorCall.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        cursorCall.close();   

                    }


                };

                builder.setCursor(cursorCall, listener, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
                builder.create().show();   
                    }




        public void sortNumber() {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String temp : allNumbers) {
            Integer count = map.get(temp);
            map.put(temp, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
        }
        printMap(map);


    }   

        public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println( entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much wrong with this it is hard to know where to begin :-(

First of all, you cannot "sort" anything using a `HashMap`. These 2 concepts are mutually exclusive.

Secondly, you have a `while` loop where you are creating and showing an `AlertDialog` for each row in your cursor. That can't be right.

Next, you are calling `setCursor()` on the `AlertDialog.Builder` and passing the `Cursor`. The dialog builder is using the data in this `Cursor` to build the content to be shown in the dialog. The fact that you have "sorted" the data is irrelevant, as you have given the dialog builder the data from your raw query.

Next, your method `sortNumber()` creates a `HashMap` and fills it, but this `HashMap` is a local variable to this method, so after the method returns, the `HashMap` is gone. You don't return the `HashMap` from the method, or store it anywhere.

If you really want the data "sorted", you should just add an "ordered by" clause to your query.

You might want to consider returning your `HashMap` from the `sortNumber()` method and then building an array of `String`s out of that and then calling `setItems()` on the dialog builder instead of using `setCursor()`.

Comment: Thanks David Wasser, you have given me the exact pointer I needed.